# How do I calculate the tensor of inertia of a non-rigid body?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

How do I calculate the tensor of inertia of a rotating **non-rigid** body? Is the usual formula:

$$T_{ij} = \int{\rho( x_ix_j - \delta_{ij} x^kx_k)d^3x}$$

still correct?

Comment: $\rho(\vec{x})$

Comment: @Eli what does it mean? That the density is not a constant, but the whole formula is still valid?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any reason for the formula for intertia to be non-applicable. (Instantaneously, of course, since in time the fluid's volume might deform, density can evolve...) It is the dynamical relations (regarding the change in angular momentum, etc.) whose rigid-body forms would not (necessarily) be applicable to a fluid.